# Iterator behaviour in flink reduceGroup

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-flink

I am creating a system that should handle huge amount of data and I need to understand how the reduce group operator works

I have a dataset where I apply a groupby and subsequently a reduceGroup
How does the iterator that is passed to the reduceGroup function behave?
is it a lazy iterator that loads data when they are requested or an eager one that prepares all the data in memory when it is created?

i am using the scala api in flink 0.9 milestone1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flink performs the group-by for a groupReduce using a sort operator. The sort operator receives a certain memory budget for sorting. As long as the data fits into this budget, the sort will happen be in-memory. Otherwise, the sort becomes an external merge-sort and spills to disk. Flink reads the sorted data stream and applies the groupReduce function "on-the-fly". The data of a group is not completely read in-memory before the function is applied. Hence, you can process very large groups if the user-function does not materialize group records itself.

Comment: Good, i have one more question, is there any documentation that describes how these methods works or at least gives some usefull tips? it would be nice having it. Actually I have some problem also finding the standard documentation for flink
i.e. I have some more doubt about join and compare it with some different possible solution

Comment: There is a bit of documentation about Flink's internals in its [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/Flink+Internals). However, I couldn't find something that describes how the processing operators are implemented. There is a [blog post](http://flink.apache.org/news/2015/03/13/peeking-into-Apache-Flinks-Engine-Room.html) on how joins are done in Flink which might be helpful.

Comment: Another [blog post](http://flink.apache.org/news/2015/05/11/Juggling-with-Bits-and-Bytes.html) describes Flink's memory management and how it operates on binary data.

Comment: very helpful! Is there any reference for the cogroup too maybe?? you should really extend such documentation for all operators: it is really useful know how they work when doing optimization

Comment: All of Flink's operators (Reduce, Sort, CoGroup, HashJoin, SortMergeJoin, ...) start spilling to disk if memory is short. The philosophy is that a developer/user should not need to worry about such things and use it like a DBMS. That's probably the reason why it is not explicitly mentioned in the documentation. But I agree, that this point should be made more clear. Thanks for the feedback! :-)